# Change the project theme in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-theme

I created some project using the light theme and now I want to change it to dark and I can't figure out how to do that. BTW, I'm not asking on how to do it in code, just how to change the project's default theme.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In the AndroidManifest.xml, under the application tag, you can set the theme of your choice. To customize the theme, press `Ctrl + Click` on `android:theme = "@style/AppTheme"` in the Android manifest file. It will open `styles.xml` file where you can change the parent attribute of the style tag.

At `parent=` in `styles.xml` you can browse all available styles by using auto-complete inside the `""`. E.g. try `parent="Theme."` with your cursor right after the `.` and then pressing `Ctrl + Space`.

You can also preview themes in the preview window in Android Studio.

[image]

Comment: After Ctrl + click on the theme, I get to styles.xml, and there I have  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">. Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar is red, can't be found: "Cannot resolve symbol 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'". What should be there?

Comment: Which version of Studio are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 0.4.4. I created another project with Holo dark theme, and now I have <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">. Still Theme.AppCompat is red and can't be resolved.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, because changing in styles.xml, changes the theme. Now why the theme name can't be resolved, that's another question.

Comment: Thank you. The problem can be the minimumSDK version in your manifest. If you are not supporting lower APIs try increasing the API level

Comment: @Shahzeb how to set android studio so that new projects always open with a predefined theme

Answer (score 15):

> Note : This answer is now out-of-date. This changes the theme in "preview" only as @imjohnking and @john-ktejik pointed out.
>   As @Shahzeb mentioned, theme can modified in res>values>styles

Android Studio 0.8.2 provides a slightly easier way to change the theme. In the preview window, you can select the theme of "Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" by clicking on the theme combo box just above the phone.[image]

Or do a ctrl + click on the @style/AppTheme in the Android manifest file. It will open styles.xml file where you can change the parent attribute of the style tag.

- Theme.Holo for a "dark" theme.
- Theme.Holo.Light for a "light" theme.

When using the Support Library, you must instead use the Theme.AppCompat themes:

- Theme.AppCompat for the "dark" theme.
- Theme.AppCompat.Light for the "light" theme.
- Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar for the light theme with a dark action bar.

Source http://forums.udacity.com/questions/100200635/choosing-theme-in-android-studio-08x

Comment: In Android 1.1.0, this just seems to change the theme in "preview" only.  It isn't updating the actual styles.xml file with a new theme.  When the app is pushed to the device, it still uses whatever theme is in the styles.xml file.  I wonder if something changed between Android Studio versions or if this was always the case?

Comment: this only changes the preview

Answer (score 5):

In Manifest theme sets with style name (AppTheme and myDialog)/ You can set new styles in styles.xml

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_my_activity2"
        android:theme="@style/myDialog"
        >
    </activity>
</application>
```

styles.xml example

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="myDialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">

</style>
```

In parent you set actualy the theme