# Android applying theme by version

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, android-theme, android-styles

I'm developing an application that starts with a listview. 
I'm in trouble with the setting of the themes for the application.
Material design can be applied to Android 5.0 and above. So I created a values-21 folder and create `styles.xml` as follow:

```
<resources>
  <!-- Inherit from the light Material Theme -->
  <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/My_LightBlue</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

In Android under 5.0 version this theme is not applied because it not read the values-21 folder.
I have to create the `styles.xml` also in values standard folder? 
It is mandatory to create a new theme to change te color of the app bar (this is my objective).

I'm a bit confused...
Thank you

Comment: You can use material design on older android versions using design support library - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html

> You can configure your app to use the material theme on devices that
>   support it and revert to an older theme on devices running earlier
>   versions of Android:
>
> 1. Define a theme that inherits from an older theme (like Holo) in
>      res/values/styles.xml.
> 2. Define a theme with the same name that inherits from the material
>      theme in res/values-v21/styles.xml.
> 3. Set this theme as your app's theme in the manifest file.

If the layouts that you design according to the material design guidelines do not use any of the new XML attributes introduced in **Android 5.0 (API level 21)**, they will work on previous versions of Android. Otherwise, you can provide alternative layouts. You can also provide alternative layouts to customize how your app looks on earlier versions of Android.

Create your layout files for Android 5.0 (API level 21) inside `res/layout-v21/` and your alternative layout files for earlier versions of Android inside `res/layout/`. For example, `res/layout/my_activity.xml` is an alternative layout for res/layout-v21/my_activity.xml.

check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27243850/compatiblity-of-material-design-to-versions-below-android-5-0) and [blog](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/)

Comment: inform me if still in confusion.@roberto garavaglia

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, if I don't apply Material Theme, which theme is applied to my application when executed on Android 6.0?

Comment: please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832114/how-to-use-device-default-theme-for-app) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762203/change-the-project-theme-in-android-studio) . you will come to know about theme concept.

Comment: Ok thank you! One more question, please :-) For the main activity I set the  Icon that is showed in the application bar. It works fine on Android 4.4 emulator but is not showed on Android 6.0. Why? I left the Default theme. Thank you!

Comment: i dont think that should happen. it should show that icon in both. may be device issue. check again using different device. please accept and upvote answer if that helped you.